# App Engine Channel API Connection and Disconnection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

I have read the section, *Tracking client connections and disconnections*, in the [Channel API for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections) documentation.

It has the following code:

```
// In the handler for _ah/channel/connected/
ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
ChannelPresence presence = channelService.parsePresence(req);
```

How would I create a handler for `_ah/channel/connected/` or `_ah/channel/disconnected`? I want to notify or alert connected users when a user is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

You just create those handlers like any other handler.

Put in the app.yaml something like:

```
- url: /_ah/channel/connected/
  servlet: com.[MY_APP].server.channel.ChannelConnected
  name: ChannelConnected
- url: /_ah/channel/disconnected/
  servlet: com.[MY_APP].server.channel.ChannelDisconnected
  name: ChannelDisconnected
```